# Android how to use material design icons in layout files

Tags: android, icons, material-design

Material design icons:

https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline

How to use these icons in layout XML file? Do I need to download these icons? e.g.

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/button_icon"
    ... />
```

Is icon size/color configurable?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can download it and use it after putting it inside the drawable folder. while you can also create vector asset by right click on drawable folder select new -> vector asset -> clip art .. and select the desirable image